# WebGL Study Material

Tags: javascript, canvas, webgl

can you please suggest some good webGL study and reference material. I just heard about it and got very exited. Any good books, E-books, Blogs would be appreciated.

and also I'm interested is it O.k. if I dig in directly into webGL or do I need some background in 3D Graphics development (or other prerequisites) to be able to work with it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

WebGL is just a port of OpenGL ES to the browser. Look for OpenGL tutorials, and appropriate them to the browser.

This looks to be a good port of the famous NeHe OpenGL tutorials for WebGL: http://learningwebgl.com/blog/?page_id=1217

Answer (score 1):

If you are just  starting with 3D, I would suggest to use one of the many 3D engines ( mrdoob's three.js is one of the best https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/ ) so you can learn various concepts quickly.

Then, from there you can start digging the basics.

Answer (score 0):

The OpenGL ES 2.0 Programming Guide http://www.opengles-book.com/ is applicable to WebGL (as WebGL is more or less a port of OpenGL ES 2.0 to JavaScript). It even has its code samples ported over to WebGL http://code.google.com/p/opengles-book-samples/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2FWebGL

If you want to get started with raw WebGL, you need some knowledge in 3D graphics programming to pull it off. Transformation matrices, lighting equations, that kind of thing. It's not super difficult or anything, just requires some study. If you want to start at a higher level, I'd recommend using one of the WebGL 3D engines. They require much less work.